# Virtualbox networking, VM inter communications, VM and host communication, VM internet communication

Tags: virtualbox

I have win10 machine. I need to create two or three virtual machines (CentOS 7), The purpose is to make an minimum environment of kubernetes dev environment. In host machine(win10 mentioned above), I could only use wireless to connect the internet. Virtualbox version is 5.2.20.

What is the networking method I shall use in order to let VMs inter-communication, VM and internet communication, VM and host communications work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked virtualbox forum and [the link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=42385) says how to do networking when windows is host.

In virtualbox global settings, in network part, I first create NAT network, Then in virtualbox settings, I create two interface, NAT for vm connecting to outside the world. Host-only for windows host talk to my virtualbox/vm (host->guest).

Using wireless network only, I create k8s mini-network in my local windows computer.

I did not try bridge network.

Answer (score 1):

You can check these settings (for network adapters) from the VirtualBox [documentation page](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).
The `Bridged` setting should satisfy all the above requirements.

[image: VirtualBox Connections]